# Status of DoFn inside ParDo

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Do we have anything which can provide the completion status of DoFn like when the function has finished it's execution?

Can we generate any trigger or anything which can give a fair idea about successful completion of all the steps written inside DoFn function?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you explain what task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can always use logging.

Answer (score 0):

Within a ParDo you will always know when the function has finished, so assuming you want to know when the entire PCollection has been processed - you can create a new Pcollection after applying the ParDo and then apply subsequent transformation on the new PCollection. E.g.

```
PCollection<T> step = ...;
PCollection<T> afterStep = step.apply(ParDo.of( new DoFn<...>(){...}));
afterStep.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<...>(){...}));
```